# How to show panel with buttons in panel?

Tags: jquery-mobile

can you please tell me how to show panel with buttons in panel(with slide show) .and display different pages on each Button click?

here is my code.
http://jsfiddle.net/ravi1989/YAA4A/

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">

    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">

    </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div> 
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
            <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
        </div>

        <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. What do you want to do?

Comment: actually i need a panel on button click .In panel there are multiple buttons.On each button click i need to go different pages

Comment: panel is display slowly using transition time .

Comment: remove your alert, panel will start working

Comment: I need multiple Button on this panel .On each button it goes to different pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/TXRjk/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div data-role="page" id="index">  
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <a href="#second" data-role="button">Jump to second page</a>
        <a href="#third" data-role="button">Jump to third page</a>        
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            First Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right">Next</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div> 
<div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <a href="#index" data-role="button">Jump to first page</a>
        <a href="#third" data-role="button">Jump to third page</a>        
    </div>    

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Second Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
<div data-role="page" id="third">
    <div data-role="panel" id="mypanel">
        <a href="#index" data-role="button">Jump to first page</a>
        <a href="#second" data-role="button">Jump to second page</a>        
    </div>    

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
        <h3>
            Third Page
        </h3>
        <a href="#index" class="ui-btn-left">Back</a>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <a data-role="button" id="open-panel">Open Pannel</a>
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
$(document).on('click', '#open-panel', function(){   
    $.mobile.activePage.find('#mypanel').panel("open");       
});
```

Comment: You understand 50% right .But 50 % wrong sorry .When you click open panel button It show panel on 30%width of page and in 70%width on same page (when button present open panel)

Comment: On clicking the second Button and third Button it show (pages on same page)is same page of 70 % width . panel is also showing.

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome..Actually when i click Second page Button it show that page only on same page.

Comment: Tell me also a platform because this works on Windows 7, last Chrome version?

Comment: i am working on mobile technologies.chrome version Version 27.0.1453.116 m

Comment: can you please add pages on right hand side while second and third button click

Comment: Sorry I dont understand you, what is that you want?

Comment: First you run this on chrome.Click "open panel".Till now it is correct.But when user click "jump to second page".It show second page with sliding only in the area (where first page present 70 %)pop first page.

Comment: When user click "jump to third page ".Show third page in front of panel same width as first and second page having sliding effect.

Comment: are you able to understand?

Comment: Actually you are showing the pages on whole screen (width).I need only on the 70% width with panel

Comment: I know it is possible to modify panel width but from my experience it is extremely complicated with a lot of CSS changes.

Comment: No i don't need any fix width requirement.But need to show second page and third page in front of panel not in whole screen